# Convergence of series in mean square

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables

> > If $\left\{X_t\right\}$ is any sequence of complex-valued random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ such that $\sup_t E\lvert X_t\rvert^2 < \infty$ and $\left\{\Psi_t\right\}$ a sequence of complex constants with $\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\lvert\Psi_t\rvert<\infty$, then the series
> >     $$
> > \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\Psi_jX_{t-j}
> > $$
> >     converges in mean square.

---

I have problems to understand the following proof:

If $\sup_t E\lvert X_t\rvert^2<\infty$ and $n>m>0$, then
$$
E\lvert\sum_{m<\lvert j\rvert\leq n}\Psi_jX_{t-j}\rvert^2=\sum_{m<\lvert j\rvert\leq n}\sum_{m<\lvert k\rvert\leq n}\Psi_j\overline{\Psi_k}E(X_{t-j}\overline{X}_{t-k})\leq\sup_t E\lvert X_t\rvert^2\left(\sum_{m<j\leq n}\lvert\Psi_j\rvert^2\right)^2\to 0
$$
as $m,n\to\infty$ and so by the Cauchy criterion the series converges in mean squares.

I do not see the equality, the inequality and why the last expression tends to $0$ as $m,n\to\infty$.

Comment: $\{X_t\}$ are complex-valued random variables and $\{\Psi_t\}$ are complex numbers, right?

Comment: I do not know. The statement does not say that. But I guess so.

Comment: What does the line above $\Psi_k$ mean?

Comment: It is not mentioned, too. Maybe conjugated complex number.

Comment: It is really hard to understand proofs if are not sure what the symbols mean..

Comment: As I added, I think, that $\lVert X-Y\rVert^2=E(X\overline{Y})$ is meant. This would lead to the first equality. So in fact, $(X_t)$ should supposed to be meant complex and the same for the constants series.

Comment: Added that the random variables are from the complex $L^2$ space. Now it should be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The first equality is using
$$ \left\lvert \sum_i a_i \right\rvert^2 = \overline{\sum_i a_i } \sum_j a_j = \sum_{i} \sum_j \bar{a}_i a_j. $$
The inequality is essentially an application of Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$ E(\bar{X}_a X_b) < \sqrt{E \lvert X_a \rvert^2 E\lvert X_b \rvert^2}, $$
followed by the bound
$$ \sum_i \sum_j \bar{a}_i a_j \bar{b}_ib_j \leqslant  \sup_{i} \lvert b_i \rvert^2 \sum_i \sum_j \bar{a}_i a_j = \sup_{i}\lvert b_i \rvert^2 \left\lvert \sum_i a_i \right\rvert^2. $$
Now applying the triangle inequality to the last bit,
$$ \left\lvert \sum_i a_i \right\rvert^2 \leqslant  \left( \sum_i \lvert a_i \rvert \right)^2, $$
and this tends to zero because the sequence $a_i$ is Cauchy. (Yes, this disagrees with the inequality you have, but this makes more sense intuitively, since we have the sum of the absolute values bounded, rather than the sum of their squares)

That's an outline. I leave you to make appropriate substitutions and sort out the details.